# Using LM393 For SLA Battery Management

Tags: batteries, comparator, charging, lead-acid

I had an old 6V SLA battery laying around, so I thought that it would be a great exercise to design a Battery Management circuit for it. Is the following circuit, based on the LM393, sufficiently good for managing a 6V 4Ah SLA battery? What can be improved?

Thanks in advance!

**DC Input:** 12

**Battery Datasheet:** [LONG WP4-6B](http://leoton-nova.com.ua/files/wbr/wp4-6.pdf)

**MOSFET Datasheet:** [FQP13N06L](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FQP13N06L-244291.pdf)

Orange LED indicates that the battery is being charged, and the green one is used as an On/Off indicator.

[image: Battery Management Circuit]

Comment: Firstly your MOSFET can not be turned on due to the fact that you are using a N-Channel MOSFET as a High Side switch. To turn it on your LM393 would have to raise its output above 12 V what is not possible in your configuration. Furthermore you should check out the charging methods for Lead Acid Batteries (e.g CCCV). Simply connecting a certain voltage is not a valid charging protocol. Once you have done that, you can figure out a circuit which is able to implement the necessary charging protocol and also add safety features such as temperature surveillance, fuses..

Comment: @Thauer it's a 6V battery, so there would be 12V or 0V at the gate. There are other issues though, like the battery powering the circuitry via FET body diode.

Comment: I don't see how it will disconnect he load at low battery voltage, or disconnect the charger when fully charged (or switch from bulk to float charging).

Comment: @Justme When the MOSFET turns on, V_GS would not be sufficient to be above the Threshold.

Comment: @Thauer the datasheet says it can pass 6.8A with 0.11 ohm resistance at Vgs=5V. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @Justme Okay, the MOSFET would turn on initially but then an enormous current only Limited by the batteries internal resistance would flow because one would be connecting 12V directly with 6V. If the DC supply could handle so much current, the Battery voltage would go up to 12 volts and the V_GS would not be sufficient to turn on the MOSFET. In reality the dc power supply will collapse and maybe be broken. But as you said there are a lot of other issues Here

Comment: After reviewing the charging methods for lead-acid batteries, I decided to go with the microcontroller route for charging - [Circuit](https://i.imgur.com/JRJhd0D.png), and use LM7805 for undervoltage protection.

Battery is charged in three stages: constant-current stage (450mA), topping stage (150mA) and float stage (300mA)

Total charge time, assuming that the battery was completely discharged, is about 20 hours - which is apparently normal for lead-acid batteries?

I am still learning about electronics, so any comment about the circuit above would be greatly appreciated!